# Running a background process and then a foreground process in a Windows Dockerfile?

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I am trying to host an API on a Windows VM using Docker. I need to use cloud sql proxy to connect to my database and then spin up my Python FastAPI. Cloud sql proxy needs to run in the background as well.

I have managed to make this work in my Dockerfile on Linux.

```
FROM python:3.8.10
...
CMD cloud_sql_proxy --port 5432 <project-name> & python -m uvicorn api:app --host 0.0.0.0
```

However, I am now trying to run the Docker image on my Windows VM and made the following modifications

```
FROM python:3.8-windowsservercore-1809
...
CMD cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances=<instance-name> -credential_file=<credential-file> & python -m uvicorn api:app --host 0.0.0.0
```

After making the above modification, the Dockerfile was successfully built without any errors. However, when I executed the following command

`docker run -p 8000:8000 -it <image-name>`

This resulted in the following error

```
At line:1 char:249
+ ... ential_file=<credential-file> & python  ...
+

The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
\+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) \[\], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
\+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

What can I do to get cloud sql proxy to run in the background with the FastAPI running in the foreground?

Comment: Your Linux image uses a Linux shell that understands `&`. The Windows image uses Powershell that doesn't understand `&`. You might look at `Start-Job` for running a process in the background.